# Expand Table with Power Query in multible colums (not in rows)

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm trying to join two Tables with Power Query and I'm helplessly overwhelmed. I created the connection and joint the two tables with a Left Outer Join.

Table 1

| Name | Industry | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Max Mustermann | IT | 16.10.21 |
| Klaus Dieter | ... | ... |

Table 2

| Name | Question |
| --- | --- |
| Max Mustermann | Question 1 |
| Max Mustermann | Question 2 |
| Klaus Dieter | Klaus Question 1 |
| Klaus Dieter | Klaus Question 2 |
| Klaus Dieter | Klaus Question 3 |

Now i want to output the following table

| Name | Industry | Date | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Max Mustermann | IT | 16.10.21 | Question 1 | Question 2 | null |
| Klaus Dieter | ... | ... | Klaus Question 1 | Klaus Question 2 | Klaus Question 3 |

I think, there must be a way with the with the Table.ExpandTableColumn command but i have no idea what to search for.

Im using excel 365.

I tried the [Expand Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNRvK.png)  but it only joins the table 1with every entry from table 2 (with matching name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with Table2 and merge in Table1 with left outer join matching on Name

[image]

Expand industry and date

[image]

Click select Name column, right click Group By

[image]

Add an index within each group so that we can number the questions. To do this, manually adjust the code generated from the group step so that it ends as follows

```
{{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table}})
```

[image]

Expand the data. Click select the index column and Transform .. pivot column and choose Question as the values column, and in Advanced Options, dont aggregate

[image]

full sample code for Table2

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"Name"}, Table1, {"Name"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"Industry", "Date"}, {"Industry", "Date"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Table1", {"Name"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Question", "Industry", "Date", "Index"}, {"Question", "Industry", "Date", "Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US")[Index]), "Index", "Question")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]